# Cant Login With IMAP From Remote Source

Tags: email, imap, dovecot

I have dovecot and postfix installed and working fine with roundcube. I can send and receive emails, but only from roundcube. I want to set this up with my phone so i can access this email account from a smartphone.

joe.bloggs is a linux user and i can log into roundcube using this as the username. note joe.bloggs@domain.com returns with a failed login.
Android requires a domain extension at the end of the username in order to accept the account. What have i configured wrong?

Answer (score 0):

First, verify you can really log in via IMAP from remote. If that is IMAP via SSL, use the openssl command to connect, otherwise telnet or the like (I'd advise strongly against using unencrypted IMAP through public networks; if you are using STARTTLS, openssl can do that, too, but I never tried it):

```
$ openssl s_client -host yourmailhost -port 993
[...]
->  * OK [CAPABILITY ...] Dovecot ready.
<-  10 login joe.bloggs complicatedpassword
->  10 OK [...] Logged in
```

If that works, you have the correct username and password.

Android (just checked with generic 4.3) just like other newer MUAs wants you to put in the full email address at first, so it can use some mechanisms — including guessing — to determine the server address. But you can later edit the username down to just the local part, or even something totally different.